# Inflection points vs critical points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I was reading what inflection and critical points are [here](https://www.math24.net/critical-points/#:%7E:text=A%20critical%20point%20x%3Dc%20is%20a%20local%20maximum%20if,is%20zero%20at%20this%20point.). If we assume that a function is defined on an open interval. Then does it mean we can say that all inflection points of the function are critical points of the function?

Comment: Yes. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)

Comment: Idea is that if a function has derivative zero at some point or it doesn't exist, then that point is called critical (which is called stationary if derivative at the point equals zero). Further, if derivative at the point is zero but the function does not attain maxima or minima at that point then that stationary point (which is a critical point) is called inflection point. For example: $f(x)=x^3$ has inflection point at $(0,0)$ in the interval $(-1,1)$ as it doesn't attain maxima/minima at origin despite $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Critical points of a function are where a function has a horizontal or vertical tangent, or is at a defined point where the function is not differentiable.

Points of inflection are where a function changes its concavity.

For example, take the function $f(x)=x^3-12x$.  Its derivative is $f'(x)=3x^2-12$ and its second derivative is $f''(x)=6x$.  It has two critical points at $(-2,16)$ and $(2,-16)$, and a single point of inflection at $(0,0)$.